# Functions and headers

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on an assignment and it's asking me to use a function with the header`Function DayofWeek(dt As Date) As String`. This program would be finding the day of the week for a specific date, if someone could explain to me how to implement this function it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should find the first day of the week from the date passed and then count the difference in days between this first day and the day of the date passed. Now start looking at the [DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) provided by the NET Framework and try something

Comment: @Steve I don't really need help with the actual problem, I'm just unsure of where to put the header for the function. Would it be inside a subroutine, such as a button being pressed?

Comment: a function is a sub routine...put it whereever you want (but not inside another like a button click). then invoke it from something like a button click

Comment: Oh, I see. I was a bit confused on how they posed the question, thank you!

Comment: a function returns something, in your case a string; a Sub routine typically *does* something (Save, Delete, DisplayNextRecord, Open...).  in OOP terms they are both *methods*.  Also, the proper term for that is not "header" but *signature*

Comment: Return dt.ToString("dddd")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as using the function, you'd probably end up doing something like this. I agree with plutonix that you should ideally not really have much in the way of code inside an event handler like code to handle a button click. Rather you should write code in a separate Sub and then invoke the sub from the button click handler - a bit like this maybe

```
Public Class Form1

    Function DayofWeek(dt As Date) As String
        'your code here ofc :)
    End Function

    Private Sub showWhatDayItIs()
        Dim todaysDay As String
        todaysDay = DayofWeek(Date.Now)
        MessageBox.Show("It's " + todaysDay + " today!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        showWhatDayItIs()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm not trying to be condescending, but this article on the Code Project is a pretty good starter for Object Oriented Programming :-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8825/Object-Oriented-Programming-In-VB-NET

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I have! And thank you for the resource, I'm in a beginner class so this will be pretty useful

Comment: Hehe no problem. Even with all the complexity that OOP and VB.Net, it can be great fun!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Public Function DayofWeek(dt As Date) As String
    Return dt.DayOfWeek.ToString()
End Function
```